# _.defer clump arguments array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a javascript function that has multiple inputs, this functions checks if certain criteria is met or not first, if not, it will delay the execution of this function to next cycle until the criteria is met.

```
function controller(obj1, obj2, obj3){ 

  if(!obj3.hasValue) {
        _.defer(controller, arguments);
        return;
   }

  //do something
}
```

However, when controller is triggered next time by _.defer, the whole arguments array is assigned to obj1. obj2 and obj3 are undefined. Is there a clean way to make the inputs remain separate just like when controller is invoked first time?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function controller(obj1, obj2, obj3){ 

  if(!obj3.hasValue) {

        var self = this
        var args = arguments
        _.defer(function(){ controller.apply(self, args) });

        return;
   }

  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
function controller(obj1, obj2, obj3){ 

  if(!obj3.hasValue) {
        _.defer(controller, ...arguments);
        return;
   }

  //do something
}
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/amvpkg4g/

```js
function controller(obj1, obj2, obj3){ 
 console.log('obj1: ' + obj1, 'obj2: ' + obj2, 'obj3: ' + obj3);
}

var arguments = [1, 2, 3];
_.defer(controller, ...arguments);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Nelson. Does _.defer handle "this" properly?

Comment: I'm not an Underscore.js expert. But I checked it's source here: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html and as it uses normal, not arrow functions, `this` is treated by the normal js rules: the value applied to this, depends on how the function is called. If you want to change it you can use apply function as in @KevinJantzer's answer.
This page has a a good explanation on `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: If the answer was useful to you please accept/upvote thanks. :)